# How to export excel from database in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a admin panel in order to show reports and other statistics to Owners. Now one of the need is to export the data in excel format with few conditions like specific date or one week data or one month data etc. How to perform this in laravel ! Kindly guide, and the data may grow to 3000+ records soon enough in couple of months , so excel should be created with all those data's too !

Answer (score 0):

> using laravel excel package (supercharge your Laravel collections and
>   export them directly to an Excel or CSV)

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

for more detail [click here](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/)

Comment: Does this helps with date specified export ?

Comment: yes this help with date see this link https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.0/exports/from-query.html#customizing-the-query

Answer (score 0):

use the package https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

```
use Excel;

Excel::create('content', function($excel) use ($data) {

            $excel->sheet('data', function($sheet) use ($data) {
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($data as $unit) {
                    $cell = 'A' . $i;
                    $sheet->setCellValue($cell, $unit);
                    $i++;    
                }
            });

        })->download('xls');
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Does this helps with date specified export ?

Comment: what do you mean ? i did not get you

Comment: refer this https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.0/exports/from-query.html#customizing-the-query

Comment: I asked, that can we query using specif date in order to download information of that date only ! anyway i wil check with the documents

Comment: that date thing is dependent on your query, you have get results of specific date first and then build excel out of that

Answer (score 0):

It works 100% ... If you want to send some data to excel... this is a great solution...

$excel->sheet('Productos SZ', function($sheet) use($products) {
                    //$sheet->fromArray($products); this is for entare table

```
                $sheet->setCellValue('A1','CANTIDAD');
                $sheet->setCellValue('B1','PRODUCTO');
                $sheet->setCellValue('C1','CATEGORIA');
                $sheet->setCellValue('D1','COMPRA 100 MIL');
                $sheet->setCellValue('E1','COMPRA 40 MIL');
                $sheet->setCellValue('F1','COMPRA 15 MIL');



                $i=2;


                foreach($products as $product)
                {
                    //celda x producto
                    $cell = 'B'.$i;

                    $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$i, $product->title.' ( $' . $product->precio_venta . ' ) ');
                    $sheet->setCellValue('C'.$i, $product->category);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$i, ' $' .$product->precio_vip);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('E'.$i, ' $' .$product->precio_master);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('F'.$i, ' $' .$product->precio_mayoreo);

                    $i++;
                }
            });

    })->download('xlsx');
```